# Spring Security + PrimeFaces paginator error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-security, datatable, paginator

I have a problem with my application.
When I start use spring security some things in PrimeFaces does not work eg. `f:setPropertyActionListener`, paginator in `p:dataTable`... I lost a day for searching fix but nothing happend.

How it's look like.

my **pom.xml**

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

my **web.xml** file

```
    <!-- Spring Security Facelets Tag Library -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <display-name>PrimeFaces Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/config/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/main/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

my **springsecurity.taglib.xml**

```
    <facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
        <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

my **applicationContext.xml**

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="xxx.yyy"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->

    <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
        <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="password" value="yyy"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>xxx.yyy</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

my **`spring-security.xml`**

```
        <intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>

        <form-login
                login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/index"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext"></password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

When I remove this lines from **web.xml**:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

everything work good (eg. paginators in `p:dataTabe`) - but no spring security.
When those lines are in web.xml spring security work good but like I wrote at begining eg. paginators in `p:dataTable` doest work.

Maybe someone have similar issue?

Comment: So, Spring security is blocking all ajax requests? Have you carefully inspected the ajax responses in browser's HTTP traffic monitor? Did they all return 401/403 or a login page or so? By the way, providing Servlet and JSP APIs along with the webapp is bad.

Comment: **BalusC** thanks for your comment. I already fix that. The problem was `<csrf/>` in **spring-security.xml** file. 
There are 2 ways to fix that:
1. `csrf disabled="true"/>`
2. Use `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>` in all `<h:form`

Comment: It's perhaps useful to know that JSF has builtin CSRF protection already.

Comment: As per your edit, please do not include answers in questions (that's only for old fashioned discussion forums). Instead, post answers as answers, here below -----------vvv This way, answered questions can be distinguished in the listings, search engine and even Google.

Comment: Yes. Good to know that

Answer (score 0):

The problem was  in spring-security.xml file. There are 2 ways to fix that: 
1. `<csrf disabled="true"/>`
2. Use

`<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>`
in all `<h:form`